Confused by CRUD::groupBy() in setupListOperation
Brand new to backpack still, and trying to understand the grouping option.
I have a polymorphic Flag table with flaggable_id and flaggable_type
I want to group my query by both of these fields and then order them by the highest count.
    protected function setupListOperation()
    {

        // Group the flags by flaggable_id and flaggable_type and select the necessary columns
        CRUD::addClause('select', 'flaggable_id', 'flaggable_type', DB::raw('count(*) as flag_count'));
        CRUD::groupBy(['flaggable_id', 'flaggable_type']);
        CRUD::orderBy('flag_count', 'desc');

        $this->crud->addColumns([
            [
                'name' => 'flaggable_type',
                'label' => 'Model Type',
                'type' => 'custom_html',
                'value' => function($entry) {
                    return class_basename($entry->flaggable_type); 
                },
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'flag_count',
                'label' => 'Flag Count',
                'type' => 'number', 
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'post_message',
                'label' => 'Post Message',
                'type' => 'custom_html',
                'value' => function($entry) {
                    if ($entry->flaggable_type === 'App\\Models\\Post') {
                        $message = \App\Models\Post::find($entry->id)->message;
                        return $message;
                    }
                    return ''; // Return an empty string if the flaggable_type is not a post
                },
            ],
        ]);
    }

The query this produces still tries to order by  'id' but I'm not selecting 'id'.
select `flaggable_id`, `flaggable_type`, count(*) as flag_count from `flags` group by `flaggable_id`, `flaggable_type` order by `flag_count` desc, `id` desc limit 10

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any help appreciated.
